# How to keep state during ajax call using CDI

Tags: java, cdi, jboss-weld

I'm using CDI (Weld) and I've faced a problem, hope you can help.
I have a series of Primefaces `selectOneMenu`, where the value selected in one is used to populate the next. Problem is, I need to use SessionScoped on my ManagedBean to get the values of the already selected items. I know that JSF has the ViewScoped that would help a lot in this case, but since I'm using CDI, this is not an option. Seam also isn't a option. There is a workaround to use, for example, RequestScoped, or I really need to use SessionScoped on my bean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at MyFaces CODI for their ViewScope or create your own CDI impl of ViewScope :)

Comment: Yeah, saw something about MyFaces CODI, but since I'm mixing too many stuff already (JSF, primefaces, richfaces, weld, and so on), I didn't want to add a new one. But for now, it looks like my best option. I wanted some workaround to not use SessionScoped or another framework, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing keeping you from using JSF managed beans and CDI beans at the same time. For example, you can have a `@javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped @javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean` and `@javax.inject.Inject` CDI beans into it. So, if view scope is the right fit to solve the problem, go ahead and use it. I've tested this with a stock GlassFish 3.1.2 server (JSF 2.1).

The other option is to use CDI's `@javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped` (http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html#d0e1841). This works best in scenarios involving a sequence of requests/views with well defined beginning and end points where you can begin and end the conversation.

Comment: No, that won't work, you'll end up getting two instances of the object, one JSF created and the other CDI created. In JSF 2.2 this won't be a problem. JSF 2.0 was finished before JSR 299 (CDI) was finished and didn't have proper integration. The MR for JSF 2 (2.1) didn't add any CDI integrations either.

Comment: As LightGuard said, this is really a problem. If I use the ViewScoped and ManagedBean, I will have trouble with other objects injected into it, since they're not CDI controlled. LightGuard, I got curious about the JSF 2.2 integration (in a later opportunity), will be possible to do exactly like Brian said?

Comment: @LightGuard, I haven't run into any problems with this. To be clear, I'm not mixing JSF and CDI annotations on the bean. The bean is annotated `@ViewScoped @ManagedBean` and has `@Inject` annotated fields. I just set a breakpoint in the constructor and it's only called once (by JSF) and does receive injections of CDI beans. Could I accidentally be using unspecified behavior? I'm running a stock GlassFish 3.1.2 (with Mojarra 2.1.6 and Weld 1.1.4). I'd like to understand this. Do you know of a JSF spec issue targeting 2.2 that I can read up on?

Comment: Which ManagedBean annotation are you using? That's th only thing that may be making this work, unless there's something Glassfish has done, or something in JSF 2.1.

Comment: @LightGuard Good question. I'm using javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean. I've updated my answer accordingly. Maybe this is something in JSF 2.1, but I wasn't able to find a good change list for 2.1 (what I did find didn't list anything obviously related to this). If you come across anything, I'd still be interested in seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

use just CDI extension to create your own scope coz your bean stay alive during ajax call back in the facescontext viewroot map
so have a look in this link : http://www.verborgh.be/articles/2010/01/06/porting-the-viewscoped-jsf-annotation-to-cdi/